# best practices on my library coded in C

Tags: c, linux, gcc, libraries

it is awkward, but until now i always copy the *.h and the *.c files to my projekts location. this is a mess and i want to change it!

i want to build my own c library and have a few questions about it.

where should i locate the  *.h files?
should i copy them in the global /usr/include/ folder or should i create my own folder in $HOME (or anywhere else)?
where should i locate the *.a files and the *.o files and where the *.c files.

i am using debian and gcc. my c projects are in $HOME/dev/c/.

i would keep my lib-sources in $HOME/dev/c/lib (if this is the way you could recommend) and copy the *.o, *.a and *.h files to the location i am asking for.

how would you introduce the lib-location to the compiler? should i add it to the $PATH or should i introduce it in the makefiles of my projekt (like -L PATH/TO/LIBRARY -l LIBRARY).

do you have anny further tips and tricks for building a own library?

Comment: why not just use `make`, create your own folders inside `$HOME` and patch the `makefile` to reference the folders?

Comment: Try to compile and install some free-software library like [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) or [gdbm](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/) or [GNU readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) from its latest *source code*. That will teach you a lot and give you some inspiration (you may need to add `/usr/local/lib/` to `/etc/ld.so.conf` then run `ldconfig`)

Comment: The title is a bit confusing. I first thought that you are coding your own [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library), but you just have *your* library *in* C (not "your libc" = "your C library"). Perhaps edit your question to improve it (make the title "best practices on my library coded in C")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend putting the files somewhere in your `$HOME` directory. Let's say you've created a library called `linluk` and you want to keep that library under `$HOME/dev/c/linluk`. That would be your project root.

You'll want a sensible directory structure. My suggestion is to have a `lib` directory containing your library and an `include` directory with the header files.

```
$PROJECT_ROOT/
    lib/
        liblinluk.so
    include/
        linluk.h
    src/
        linluk.c
    Makefile
```

**Compiling:** When you want to use this library in another project, you'd then add `-I$PROJECT_ROOT/include` to the compile line so that you could write `#include <linluk.h>` in the source files.

**Linking:** You would add `-L$PROJECT_ROOT/lib -llinluk` to the linker command line to pull in the compiled library at link time. Make sure your `.so` file has that `lib` prefix: it should be `liblinluk.so`, not `linluk.so`.

A `src` directory and `Makefile` are optional. The source code wouldn't be needed by users of the library, though it might be helpful to have it there in case someone wants to remake the `.so` file.

Comment: thanks @John Kugelman, i will try this configuration. (everything is better than my actual copy'n'paste strategy)

Comment: No, you might consider a system install, on Linux include directory would go into `/usr/local/include/` and shared library into `/usr/local/lib`, then run `ldconfig`

Comment: Might be worth mentioning `C_INCLUDE_PATH` and `LIBRARY_PATH`/`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as persistent alternatives to `-I` and `-L`.

Answer (score 3):

As I commented, you should try first to build and install from its source code several free software libraries, e.g.  like [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) or [gdbm](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/) or [GNU readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) etc (don't use any distribution package, but compile and install these from source code). This will teach you some good practice.

You probably want to install these libraries *system-wide*, not for your particular user. Then, assuming that your library is called `foo` (you need to give it some name!),

- the header files `*.h` go into `/usr/local/include/foo/`
- the shared objects (dynamic libraries) go into `/usr/local/lib/libfoo.so` (with perhaps some version numbering)
- if relevant, static library go into `/usr/local/lib/libfoo.a`

You need to add once `/usr/local/lib/` into `/etc/ld.so.conf` and run [ldconfig(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ldconfig.8.html)

and you *usually* don't want to copy any source file `*.c` or object file `*.o`
(except for [homoiconic programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity), [bootstrapped compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(compilers)), [Quine programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)), [generated C code](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/257873/40065), etc... See [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) or [Jacques Pitrat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Pitrat) systems as an incomplete example of self generated C or C++). In *some weird* cases, you may want to copy such "source" or "generated C" code under `/usr/src/`.

Read [Program Library HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/) (and later, Drepper's paper: [How To Write Shared Libraries](http://people.redhat.com/drepper/dsohowto.pdf))

You could consider making your library known by [pkg-config](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/). Then install some `foo.pc` under `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/`

BTW, I strongly suggest you to publish your library as [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), perhaps on [github](http://github.com/) or elsewhere. You'll get useful feedback and could get some help and some bug reports or enhancements.

You probably should use some builder like `make` and have an `install` target in your `Makefile` (hint: make it use the `DESTDIR` convention).